# SVN: When I update the package, svn doesn't add the files and any changes in this package

Tags: svn

screenshoot after updating package

[image]

I am working in IntelliJ IDEA. When I update the package, svn doesn't add the files and any changes in this package. Version Contol reports: All files are up-to-date. But security' folder is green and doesn't have any class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"svn revert --depth infinity" solved my problem